# Задача создать динамически расширяющийся INPUTTEXT в JSF

Tags: html, jsf

Есть следующая часть кода. Необходимо сделать так чтобы inputtext расширялся до определенного количества символов по мере введения этих символов. А по достижении допустим длинны в 50 символов, появлялась дополнительная строка внизу(тоже на 50 символов).

```
<h:inputText value="#{component.entity.textUa}" id="textUa" maxlength="100"
title="#{cardOrderPurposesMsg.text_ua}" required="true"
requiredMessage="#{commonMsg.empty_field_error}"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Такие вещи делаются не с помощью jsf:

```html
<input type="text" style="width: 8px;" onkeydown="this.style.width = ((this.value.length + 1) * 8) + 'px';">
```

Comment: А можете подсказать что изменить чтобы указать конечное число символов? Можно ли указать какое-то начальное значение в 200 пикселей к примеру? И можно ли как-то сделать так чтобы по достижении определенного количества, например в 50 символов, появлялась дополнительная строка снизу.

Comment: Чтобы ограничить расширение инпута двадцатью символами, например, нужно значение атрибута `onkeydown` заменить на `this.style.width = ((this.value.length < 20 ? this.value.length + 1 : 20) * 8) + 'px';` А вот вторую строку можно обеспечить либо заменой input на textarea, либо использованием editable div, но это уже другой, более сложный вопрос.

Comment: А можете помочь с editable div?

Comment: Правила ресурса не рекомендуют ведение длинных переписок в комментариях и решение двух и более проблем в одном вопросе. Вот вам [пример](https://jsfiddle.net/TheDeadOne/xgq8uyyz/) для старта и экспериментов.

Comment: в любом случае спасибо. разобрался с текстареа, нужно теперь только задать чтобы после 100 символа не можно было больше печатать. но это уже другой только что созданный вопрос)